# Software Update in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

Can anyone who has upgraded to Mountain Lion confirm that software updating is now done through the App Store and no longer through the Software Update utility?

If this is the case, does this mean different family members must sign in to the same account or use the same account just to update the OS? In my case,  purchased OS X Lion with my Apple ID, one of my family signed to my account once in order to download Lion, but they can update their system using the the classic Software Update utility afterwards. Now it seems they'll need to sign into my account every time for any update, or we'll have to create a new Apple ID just for this purpose.

Comment: I can confirm Software Update launches the App Store now. For updating apps you do need to authenticate with the account that downloaded the app originally. I'm not sure though how the MAS will handle OS updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS updates are in a different group in the Mac App Store, and neither checking for them nor downloading them requires you to be logged in to any account at all, so you should not have any problems.

Also note that you could simply enable automatic updates in System Preferences to avoid having to manage OS updates yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The term **Software Update** does appear in the  menu, but clicking it opens the Updates tab in the **App Store** app.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Daniel installed the Daniel voice. That's about right I guess :).

Comment: Do you need to be signed in for installing the OS updates?